# How to get an image url in this json file in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, mobile-application

in this json file I want to get **original_ur** but when i cant get it , can some one help me how to get it please

```
{
    "orders": {
        "order_items":[
        {
            "product_min":{
                    "colors":[
                         {
                        "media":[
                              {
                             "original_url": b 
     "https://royalpetiq.com/royalpet2/public//storage/10628/msg5212971698-890.jpg",

                              }
                       ]
                    }
                  ]
               }
             }
          ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: yourJson['orders']['product_min']['colors']['media']['original_url']

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go on quicktype id site and create model from this json after just creat object of that claass and parse this json response and after that you can get valu like
x.orders.order_items[0].product_min.colors[0].media[0].original_url

Answer (score 0):

here is your json path

```
x.orders.order_items[0].product_min.colors[0].media[0].original_url
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
  
  var json = """{
"orders": {
    "order_items":[
    {
        "product_min":{
                "colors":[
                     {
                    "media":[
                          {
                         "original_url": "https://royalpetiq.com/royalpet2/public//storage/10628/msg5212971698-890.jpg"

                          }
                   ]
                }
              ]
           }
         }
      ]
  }
}""";
  
  var data = jsonDecode(json);
  var url = data["orders"]["order_items"][0]["product_min"]["colors"][0]
      ["media"][0]["original_url"];
  
  print("Url: $url");
  
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

I think your json should be like that.
Here the url has a b at the beginning and a comma after the url which is not the correct syntax for json

Comment: Do add null check for safety first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).